# Problem reading spreadsheet on onedrive using C# Microsoft Interop Excel

Tags: c#, excel

When I try to read a spreadsheet that is on onedrive, it will sometimes read the spreadsheet with no problems, and other times it will give me a popup saying that excel is being used by another proccess.

```
workbooks = excel.Workbooks;
workbook = workbooks.Open(name, ReadOnly: true); // Error sometimes occurs here
```

I have also made sure to do garbage collection and release Com objects of everything.

```
try
{
  workbooks = excel.Workbooks;
  workbook = workbooks.Open(name, ReadOnly: true); // Error sometimes occurs here
}
catch {}
finally
{

  if (workbook != null)
  {
     workbook.Close(false);
     workbooks.Close();
     Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbook);
     Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbooks);
  }
  excel.Quit();
  Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excel);
  GC.Collect();
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
  workbook = null;
  workbooks = null;
  excel = null;
}
```

Im not sure exactly why this is specifically happening with files on onedrive, and also why its not a frequent issue